# Obtaining the last character in a stringstream without copying its whole buffer

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, seek

If I use this code:

```
template <typename Streamable>
/* ... */
std::stringstream ss;
ss << function_yielding_a_Streamable();
auto last_char = ss.str().back();
```

then (I believe) a copy of the string in `ss`'s buffer will need to be created, just for me to get the last character, and it will then be destroyed. Can I do something better instead? Perhaps using the `seekp()` method?

Comment: Why put the `string` into the `stringstream` in the first place?

Comment: @Sean: Fair question, see edit.

Comment: Presumably, it doesn't *have* to be a `stringstream`? Perhaps you could use a custom stream instead.

Comment: @user2079303: I suppose... but wouldn't that be overkill?

Comment: @einpoklum depends on how big buffer `function_yielding_a_Streamable` generates and whether you need any of it except for the last character. If it generates megabytes of data, I think it would be worth it to store only what you need rather than the entire buffer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
char last_char;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << function_yielding_a_Streamable();
ss.seekg(-1,ios::end);//get to the last character in the buffer
ss>>last_char;
```

Comment: Wouldn't I then also need to seek back (e.g. if I wrap this in a function taking an ostringstream& which I want to act cleanly)?

Comment: @einpoklum sorry for the late replay, i believe you can do that using *seekp(0)* to seek to to the beginning for insertion. I suppose you meant to say pass *stringstream&* rather than *ostringstream&* since with the latter you can't access the extraction *operator>>* to read the last character.